# How to change ~/.cache directory during the Go build process

Tags: go

Go build touches ~/.cache which is undesirable.

How can I change the location of this directory?

Answer (score 17):

> The cache defaults to the operating system-defined user cache
>   directory but can be moved by setting $GOCACHE.

Source: [article from rsc](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/qfa3mHN4ZPA)

Answer (score 6):

From [the official documentation](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Build_and_test_caching):

> Build and test caching
>
> The go command caches build outputs for reuse in future builds. The default
> location for cache data is a subdirectory named go-build in the standard user
> cache directory for the current operating system. Setting the GOCACHE
> environment variable overrides this default, and running 'go env GOCACHE'
> prints the current cache directory.

Note that the aforementioned `go env GOCACHE` command can be used to make sure
that `GOCACHE` points to a desirable location before e.g.: building with
`go build`.  Example:

```
$ go env GOCACHE
/home/user/.cache/go-build
$ GOCACHE=/foo/bar
$ export GOCACHE
$ go env GOCACHE
/foo/bar
```