# Change GOCACHE default folder on Ubuntu Linux

Tags: go

I must put all the files GO creates inside the structure of GO, not scattered. While changing GOPATH and GOROOT, I noticed the build folder on ~/.cache/go-build.

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983303/how-to-change-cache-directory-during-the-go-build-process) didn't help at all, not either [the article it links](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-dev/qfa3mHN4ZPA). It doesn't seems to deal directly with that. How can I change it?

Edit: the problem isn't how to find the GOCACHE, which I already know that can be viewed by `go env GOCACHE`, but ***how can I change that folder***.

I've tried to add to ~/ .bashrc:
`export GOCACHE=$HOME/path/to/folder`, and now when I use `go env GOCACHE`, it points to the new folder but still tries to send files to `~/.cache/go-build`. The log file is now returning the following error:

`go: disabling cache (/home/<me>/.cache/go-build) due to initialization failure: mkdir /home/<me>/.cache/go-build: permission denied`

Comment: Hi, have you tried to set GOCACHE?

Comment: Not yet. I'm new with GO and there's no obvious answer for that on Google. It's just set it like GOPATH and GOROOT?

Comment: You can execute `go env` to know the environment variables.

Comment: I did that to find the ~/.cache/go-build folder before. Tried to set GOCACHE in the environment variables, restarted and now "go env" says the folder changed. BUT when I run any go code, the same folder is still used.

Comment: @CleitonOliveira why do you think that ~/.cache/go-build is still being used after setting GOCACHE to another location? Did you try to remove ~/.cache/go-build after changing GOCACHE?

Comment: are you using ``sudo``?

Comment: Thank you, @Everton, that helped a lot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error shown

```
go: disabling cache (/home/<me>/.cache/go-build) due to initialization failure: mkdir /home/<me>/.cache/go-build: permission denied
```

Is because the directory `/home/<me>/.cache/go-build` does not exist and permissions to create a new directory aren't there.  This shouldn't happen, it seems like some unknown factor in your build process is clobbering the GOCACHE settings

Do you literally have a user called `<me>`?  That's quite unusual and ill advised, as `<>` are shell meta characters

As for setting the path, see https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/cache/default.go
and https://golang.org/pkg/os/#UserCacheDir

If GOCACHE env variable is set then it uses that.  If not it uses os.UserCacheDir which is usually $HOME/.cache but can be overridden, see the docs

The simple answer is to set the GOCACHE env variable to be inside your Go containment area

Just to clarify.  Go compiler and tools run inside another environment.

This other environment has variables set inside it, which Go will honour

On Linux systems, this environment is usually the bash shell.  In the bash shell to set the GOPATH the command "export GOPATH=$HOME/go" is often used, to set up a GOPATH to a folder called go in the home directory of the current user.  To set the GOCACHE set the variable in the environment you are using and Go will pick it up

Comment: I appreciate your answer but your solution is exactly my question.

Comment: I've added some clarification.  If this doesn't address the issue you have then it would be helpful if you thought about how to alter the question to show why

Comment: After put the `export` to bashrc and completely removing the old `cache/go-cache` folder, the system finally worked well. Strange was to see the system still trying to use the old folder even after the change and restarting the system. Also, <me> was just to hide the real name of the droplet. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

```
cd $HOME    
sudo chown -R <yourname>.<yourname> .cache/go-build
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, using a Mac.

I solved it by unlocking the folder, see prints below

The first one is a sign in Finder showing the folder is locked
And the second is where to unlock folder

[image: Folder locked sign]

[image: Where to unlock folder]