# Where are the interfaces of the packages in a Go module stored?

Tags: go

I have a Go module consisting of two packages, A and B.  Package A uses package B.  I type

```
go install ./...
```

to build everything in the module.  I then make a change to one file in package A.  If I then type `go install` again, the compiler must recompile A.  It does not have to recompile B.  But in order not to recompile B, the interface of B must be stored somewhere, for the compiler to read.  But I have looked everywhere (in the module tree, in my GOPATH, in ~/go) and I cannot find any object file or archive file for B anywhere.  Is it really the case that the second `go install` recompiles everything in the entire module, including the unaffected package?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change ~/.cache directory during the Go build process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48983303/how-to-change-cache-directory-during-the-go-build-process)

Comment: Thanks.  I'll further answer my own question by saying that the -x option to `go install` shows the cache files that the tool is accessing, but there is a caveat: If you just `touch` a source file and then reissue `go install`, no cache information will be shown, because `go install` is smart enough to figure out that nothing needs to be redone and that the cache does not need to be read.  To watch `go install` access the cache, you must change the contents of one of your source files.

Answer (score -1):

Try
GOBIN=/usr/local/bin/ go install (Or other dir)